# error: Not a recognized archive type: pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

Whenever I attempt to install `pip` in my terminal, I get the following:

```
error: Not a recognized archive type: pip
```

I've been following the guide in [this link](https://ahmadawais.com/install-pip-macos-os-x-python/) and after entering `python get-pip.py`, the above mentioned appears. I've searched Google and I noticed others are having installation issues but with different messages. Mine says not a recognized archive type while another would say for example 'command not found'.

Any known reason for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to install ``pip`` yourself? The system Python and versions installed by common package managers (e.g. brew) already ship with ``pip``. Also, please [edit] your question to show the exact command you are running, as well as the entire traceback.

Comment: He seems to have used `easy_install`, because the error is on `setuptools` source, here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/dabd73137f97145cc95c114937c95b217ac76876/setuptools/archive_util.py#L60